# Custom types in controller's action in playframework

Tags: scala, playframework, controller, playframework-2.0

Is there a way to use "typesafe" parameters for action in play framework? Instead of userId being a String, it could be of a more typesafe class like in the example below:

```
case class UserId(v: String) extends AnyVal

object UsersController extends Controller {

  def get(userId: UserId) = Action {
    Ok(Users.find(userId))
  }

}
```

This would also make the test-code more typesafe:

```
val userId: UserId = ....
FakeRequest(routes.UsersController.get(userId))
```

The code above would give a compiler error if you accidentally passed in something else.

...But to get there you would have to convert it to the correct type in the `.routes`-file somehow..?

Comment: Is it what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414473/implement-your-own-object-binder-for-route-parameter-of-some-object-type-in-play ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PathBindable[A]` trait.

http://julien.richard-foy.fr/blog/2012/04/09/how-to-implement-a-custom-pathbindable-with-play-2/